# Targeting single directory for rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have edited this question to use the actual URLs. I need the url

```
http://westernmininghistory.com/mine_db/main.php?page=mine_detail&dep_id=10257227
```

To be rewritten like

```
http://westernmininghistory.com/mine_detail/10257227/
```

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /mine_db/main.php?page=$1&dep_id=$2 [L]
```

Which works on this page but breaks every other page on the site. I was wondering if there was a way to force the rewriterule to only operate on files within the mine_db directory. I had tried RewriteCond but with no success:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mine_db
```

I really don't know they proper syntax for this though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of your rule can be shortened and written without needing `RewriteCond`. Also it appears that you want to capture 2 variables after `test_db`.

You can try this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(mine_detail)/([0-9]+)/?$ /mine_db/main.php?page=$1&dep_id=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Which will work with URIs like `/mine_detail/12345` (trailing slash is optional). Also note that above rewrite will happen silently (internally) without changing the URLi in browser. If you want to change URL in browser then use `R` flag as well like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(mine_detail)/([0-9]+)/?$ /mine_db/main.php?page=$1&dep_id=$2 [QSA,L,NC,R]
```

Comment: This didn't work. I have edited the original question with the actual URLs. Thanks!